# how to create http server

Tags: http, httpserver

I'm trying to go live with my website. I found a question here on stackoverflow that had all the steps I have to follow, and the first is to create an HTTP server. I followed some python tutorial on Youtube and also howCode's tutorial in which I have a python file that creates the server, as shown, but everything I try to run gets me a "localhost refused to estabilish a connection" error or, I think, the 404.

```py
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler


class Serv(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.path = '/index.html'
        try:
            file_to_open = open(self.path[1:]).read()
            self.send_response(200)
        except:
            file_to_open = "File not found"
            self.send_response(404)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes(file_to_open, 'utf-8'))


httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8080), Serv)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

How can I create a simple HTTP server, so I can then do all the other steps so my website can be live and for everyone to access it?

Comment: Well, then obviously you had the wrong tutorial or didn't follow it correctly. But no one will know, because you don't show us what you have tried ... And also depending on what you mean by "put the website live", running a http server on your local computer may not be the correct approach.

Comment: @derpirscher ok, I edited my question to include past tries! Let's say I'm building a website, a simple website. I want the website to be accessible for everyone and I don't expect for it to have many users, so I read the host it locally was ok. Also, I have tried DigitalOcean but it doesn't accept my card, and I couldn't find any more free options, so that's why I'm trying it locally too, I guess

Comment: Hosting it locally would only work if you've opened your network sufficiently to allow the network traffic to reach the location you're hosting the site at. That means firewalls etc. In general, for hosting a static website, you don't need to create an HTTP server. The hosting service (Digital Ocean, AWS, Azure, Go Daddy etc) provides that for you. You just upload your static files (html, css, js, images etc) and then they serve them for you. You just need to pick the proper static hosting service from your hosting provide. Ex: Digital Ocean has an App Platform for hosting static sites.

Comment: For serving a website for public access, running a local http server certainly is not the best option. There are several low cost services that provide that functionality way better and more reliable. And if you really decide to setup your own web server, you are probably better off installing an existing software like nginx, Apache http server or even iis if you are on windows, especially if you don't have too much programming skills.

Comment: @derpirscher thank you, i'll have that in account!